# Is it possible to permanently rename your pets?

Tags: guild-wars-2

In Guild Wars 2, I play a Ranger, and I can charm a variety of pets and make them my own. On the pet management screen I get the option to rename the pets and in the instance of my little spider I have:

[image]

However, if I change the pet that is active in that pet slot (in this case the primary pet slot), my spider loses its name, and reverts back to it's default name of Juvenile Jungle Spider:

[image]

Is it possible to permanently rename my pets in a way that I don't have to keep resetting it every time I change the pets I have in my rotation?

Comment: Glad to see your mountain lion is no longer your default aquatic animal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is currently not possible.

It is, however, a [known issue](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/professions/ranger/Ranger-Bug-List/first#post117125). Though, I have heard conflicting reports as to whether or not an official fix will ever be rolled out for something as minor as this, given the number of other [ranger bugs.](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/List_of_Ranger_bugs)

Comment: holy-wtf that is a *lot* of ranger bugs...

Comment: This **SO** needs a fix. It's such a petty issue, but it gets right up my nose! ¬¬